# Problems in Android Library regarding to SQLCipher

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

This is my program.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InitializeSQLCipher();
    }



         private void InitializeSQLCipher() {
                SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);

                File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("demo.db");

                databaseFile.mkdirs();

                databaseFile.delete();

                SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, "test123", null);


                database.execSQL("create table t1(a, b)");

                database.execSQL("insert into t1(a, b) values(?, ?)", new Object[]{"one for the money",
                                                                                "two for the show"});
         }
}
```

I have add some three libraries in this program which is in this link ........
https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher

Now My query is i am getting the following errors. How to overcome to get a perfect solution ...

```
04-12 11:47:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 11:47:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
04-12 11:47:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): at com.example.testproject.MainActivity.InitializeSQLCipher(MainActivity.java:43)   
04-12 11:47:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): at com.example.testproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
04-12 11:47:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-12 11:47:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611) .... and so on ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find your library.  If its a jar, did you put it in your libs folder  and add it to the project?  Did you export it on the export tab?  If its a library project, did you add it as a library?  If so did it add the reference in project.properties?

If all of those are right, try a make clean, eclipse may just need to recompile everything.

Comment: There are 2 library in this link https://github.com/sqlcipher/andrid-database-sqlcipher and also i have imported some extra 2 libraries after then also im getting this error ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, even after the library had the requisite jar file. Solved it, by modifying the Proguard config file. Apparently, Proguard was optimizing the APK by removing the lib. So if you are using Proguard, you might want to look into the config file.